# Serialising an object to JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, javascriptserializer

I am trying to serialise an object to JSON and cannot figure out why a whole bunch of properties are being ommitted. For reference, I have tried using the  `DataContractJsonSerializer` for the same to no avail as it generates a `StackOverflowException`.

Essentially, I have a `Basket` object:-

```
public class Basket : BusinessListBase<Basket, BasketItem>
{
    private Voucher _voucher;
    public Voucher Voucher;

    public decimal GrandTotalIncVat
    {
        get { return Math.Round(BasketTotalIncVat + DeliveryTotalIncVat, 2); }
    }
}
```

The code I have for serialising to Json is:-

```
JavaScriptSerializer objSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
StringBuilder objSB = new StringBuilder();
objSerialiser.ConvertToType<T>(value);
objSerialiser.Serialize(value, objSB);
return objSB.ToString();
```

The call to this Json code works fine but the resulting string only contains the properties for `BasketItem` and not `Basket`, which is really what I want.

What's the problem here?

I am now calling the serializer with:-

```
universalVariableBase.BasketData = BasketManager.SessionBasket;
JsonHelper.ToJson<Core.UniversalVariable>(universalVariableBase)
```

and the Serializer is simply:-

```
public static string ToJson<T>(this T value)
{   
     return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Therefore the value in this case is the Basket object which is stored as BasketManager.SessionBasket

and I can call something like

```
((Basket)BasketManager.SessionBasket).GrandTotalIncVAT
```

and it contains a value.

However, when I serialize this, there are only members of BasketItem as a list and no Basket so GrandTotalIncVAT does not appear.

To answer your question, BusinessListBase is a third party object from CSLA.NET. I didn't implement this approach so I am wondering if this is causing some weirdness somewhere.

Comment: Could you share some more information: What is T in `objSerializer.ConvertToType<T>`? What type is value? What is a BusinessListBase?

Comment: Please post all your code, whats T? How is your serialiser getting called? You've only given us half the information we need here?

Comment: Circular references, possibly. They won't be handled nicely be many/any serializer(s), either omitting them silently or by throwing an error.

Answer (score -1):

you can use newtonsoft json converter. It is easy to use and serializes in just a few lines

```
tring jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, conv);
```

Comment: I'm using the NewtonSoft serialiser and it works really well, thanks for the recommendation.